# Не устанавливается pyaudio

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.7, pyaudio

Когда ввожу команду `pip install pyaudio` в терминал `pycharm`.

Всё почти устанавливается, но в конце выдаёт фатальную ошибку:

```
error: command 'D:\\VISUALSTUDIO\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
 ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
 Complete output from command c:\users\guest\pycharmprojects\voiceassistant\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Guest\\AppData\\Local\\Temp
\\pip-install-hv0ktsus\\pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --reco
rd C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dkrka3oo\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\guest\pycharmprojects\voiceassistant\
venv\include\site\python3.7\pyaudio:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
    D:\VISUALSTUDIO\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\guest\pycharmprojects\voiceassistant\venv\include -IC:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
-32\include -IC:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include -ID:\VISUALSTUDIO\VC\INCLUDE -ID:\VISUALSTUDIO\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x
86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/_portaudi
omodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
    error: command 'D:\\VISUALSTUDIO\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\guest\pycharmprojects\voiceassistant\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Guest\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hv0ktsus\\
pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Guest\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-record-dkrka3oo\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\guest\pycharmprojects\voiceassistant\venv\include\site\python
3.7\pyaudio" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hv0ktsus\pyaudio\
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Думаю, главное в том тексте с ошибкой `src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: portaudio.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Тут https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/ написано что последняя поддерживая версия -- 3.6. Мб в этом дело? Попробуйте поставить 3.6 и на него попробовать установить pyaudio

Comment: Скиньте пожалуйста ссылку на скачивание питон 3.6.8,не могу найти на оффициальном сайте

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-368/ ? Там внизу таблица с установщиками